# Ubuntu minimal install ISO with LUKS support?

Tags: installation, encryption

So if I want to encrypt my whole HDD with e.g.: LUKS (are there any better solutions? - e.g.: in performance?) then I have to download&burn a "ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso" CD. That's ok, I understand.

The Question: Are there any minimal ISO's (like the Debian netinstall CD) ***WITH** LUKS support?

So that I just have to download an ISO that weights a couple of MByte's and install it using LUKS so that I could have a [fully encrypted HDD](http://xercestech.com/full-system-encryption-for-linux.geek)?

Comment: maybe installing on encrypted LVM ( it is option when youre formatting drives in minimal iso ) or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystem 
will work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#64-bit%20PC%20%28amd64,%20x86_64%29

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.